# Django: When doing an include of URL's, should I specify project.app or just app

Tags: python, django, django-urls

When including an app's URL's in the project's `urls.py`, my coding partner does it this way:

```
('^stops/', include('stops.urls'))
```

However, [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) specifies the following syntax:

```
('^clients/', include('project_name.app_name.urls'))
```

His way has worked. Is there a reason to specify the project name at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your `PYTHONPATH` setting and the structure of your projects and apps.

We have many, many projects.  Each with several apps.  All are on our `PYTHONPATH`, so the project name is essential.

If you have only one project, and the top-level project directory is on your `PYTHONPATH`, then each app can be resolved separately and you can't use the project name.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends upon if the app is inside your project, or a reusable one.

I have a fresh virtualenv for every project, and use a separate mercurial repository for each app. These are then installed into the system path (either in editable form for development, or in non-editable form for deployment), meaning I have `<appname>` on the `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

if on the shell you run

```
import this
```

you will see that there is a zen of python  ''explicit is better than implicit''  hence thats the reason to specify the project name.